# PHP | Mysql how to stop from inserting if any record with same id overdate exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

Well, I have this attendance system who mark an attendance every day, well what I am looking is for a restriction other than PHP code like a restriction that can restrict users to enter duplicate record over time.
For e.g I have already marked my attendance .`myself`

> DATE 22-05-2018 and trackingid = 1

if I try to insert mark attendance one more time it should not insert the statement.

It can be done via php and its a long code and i mean like it is possible but is there any way around with MySQL , through which we can make 2 columns unique if they both already exist just dont let user insert .

Comment: use can set unique_index in mysql through SQL Query

Comment: What have you tried? And what's the problem if it's a long code? It looks like it's just one select query and one condition.

Comment: unique index through sql query ?Basically what i need is one unique index for 2 columns . Like i can make a single column unique and it wont let any duplicate record to insert but i want this function only happen when there is a duplicate of 2 columns not one

Comment: I was thinking of a way arround from sql if there is even a possibility it would have been so advanced and some thing new .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use unique_index on your columns

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`columnOneName`, `columnTwoName`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following like sql while creating your table:-

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`columnOne` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`columnTwo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`columnThree` varchar(128),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `columnOne_columnTwo_unique_index` (`id_box_elements`,`id_router`)
);
```